# What are outstanding problems with the Recursive Three-Way Merge algorithm?

Tags: git, algorithm, merge

Git implements a [recursive 3-way merge](https://git-scm.com/docs/merge-strategies) strategy that [solves problems with criss-crossing histories](http://codicesoftware.blogspot.com/2011/09/merge-recursive-strategy.html), but what problems does this strategy NOT solve?

**The best account I've found so far is on the [old revctrl wiki](http://web.archive.org/web/20100905180220/http://revctrl.org/CrissCrossMerge):**

> Recursive three-way merge usually provides the right answer, however there are some edge cases. For example, conflict markers can be matched incorrectly, because they aren't given any special semantic meaning for the merge algorithm, and are simply treated as lines. In particular, there are (somewhat complicated) cases where the conflict markers of two unrelated conflicts get matched against each other, even though the content sections of them are totally unrelated.
>
> Also, recursive merge can do some of the same invalid merges as [SimpleWeaveMerge](http://web.archive.org/web/20100905180220/http://revctrl.org/SimpleWeaveMerge) does, which are described below, although exactly what it does under those circumstances is highly dependant on the details of the 3 way merge algorithm, but it isn't clear that tweaking the 3-way merge algorithm to be more conservative about showing conflicts will make such problems go away. Basically, including the conflict is creating a weave, and that introduces the problems which weaves have.
>
> Finally, recursive three-way merge has all the inherent problems of [ImplicitUndo](http://web.archive.org/web/20100905180220/http://revctrl.org/ImplicitUndo). In particular, merging together multiple things which merge cleanly will sometimes give different answers depending on the order in which the merges happen. In fact, it's possible in a never-ending criss-cross case for a value to flip-flop until the end of time without ever getting a single unclean merge. This is a very fundamental problem, and fixing it requires first deciding what one wants to have happen in such cases, because what is appropriate behavior is unclear.

However, these problems are vaguely stated.  What are specific situations where recursive 3-way merge breaks, and in what ways does it break?

Can anyone show some version control histories that it screws up?

(I'm NOT asking about problems in the diff algorithm, such as understanding source code semantics, or conflict resolution.  Let's presume the user is happy resolving conflicts and using a naive string diff.)

Comment: In practice what I see with 3-way merge elsewhere is that if two people add e.g. new code to different parts of a file, everything is fine, but if two people both decide to just stick their new code at the bottom of the file, merge can't tell whether you have two different appends to the end of the file or two competing attempts at making the same change so it throws a conflict. So it is a good idea to put new code in a distinctive place, not just shove it on at the bottom of the file.

Comment: @mcdowella You're describing an issue with the diff algorithm, which is NOT a problem with the 3-way merge strategy. The issue of two people writing to the same part of a file happens no matter which merge strategy you use.

Answer (score 2):

Reddit user /u/PascaleDaVinci proposes an issue [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/programming/comments/1h4x3f/the_state_of_the_art_in_merge_technology/cardhvv):

> ```
>   A
>  / \
> B   B
> |
> A
> ```
>
> The programmer introduced a change in both branches, then reverted it on one side. A three-way merge will reintroduce it without a conflict, though it is not clear whether that is the programmer's intent, as she rejected the change on one side, but kept it on the other. Because three-way merges ignore the history of changes in between the revisions, they don't see the ambiguous programmer intent and thus can't identify that ambiguity.

Depending on your interpretation of what the merge algorithm should do, you might call this a problem, or not.

Comment: I think it is a problem because it will merge automaticaly without the developer being aware of the situation, and such merge might be not what the developer wanted.

Comment: This is a real problem that has happened to me. I don't believe that it's only a `git revert` but simply an additional commit that effectively reverted a previous change.

Answer (score 2):

(This isn't a complete answer to the question, but it might help derive an answer.)

It turns out that the issue of criss-cross merges in a version DAG are analogical to the definition of [semilattices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semilattice) in the mathematical field of [order theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_theory), which are used in CRDT research to define data structure version histories that can be merged without error:

- CRDTs are analagous to version control systems
- A CRDT semilattice is equivalent to a version control DAG if the DAG contains no criss-cross versions
- The 3-way recursive merge strategy converts a criss-cross DAG into a valid semilattice, by ensuring that there is a unique "least common ancestor" aka "lowest upper bound".
- A "least common ancestor" (in the field of version control) is equivalent to the concept of a "lowest upper bound" (in lattice order theory).

To summarize: CRDTs require a semilattice.  A semilattice requires that every pair of entries have a unique lowest upper bound.  3-way merge in version control also requires that there is a unique least common ancestor, and has an algorithm to create one if not.

Conclusion: It's possible that CRDT research has a mathematical proof that a perfect merge is possible if the version graph forms a semilattice, and if so, that proof could be generalized to show that recursive 3-way merge is also perfect.  One good lead might be to analyze the usefulness of the [algebraic operators of a semilattice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semilattice#Algebraic_definition), which only hold when there is a unique least common ancestor.  These operators might be necessary for merging—and if so, then it is necessary to have a least common ancestor.